wcf decompress response in net 8 maui
I try to connect to an old asmx webservice with a maui (net 8) application. The request works uncompressed but the service always sends back compressed gzip response, no matter the 'Accept-Encoding'. I tried to enable Decompressionenabled but seems to do nothing.
What I've tried on the client side:
                var ep = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://intranetServer/Service/WebSerice.asmx"));
                WebServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration soap = WebServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.WebServiceSoap12;
                client = new WebServiceSoapClient(soap, ep);
               
                
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
                
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                textBindingElement.MessageVersion = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.CreateVersion(System.ServiceModel.EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressingVersion.None);
                result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement();
                
                httpBindingElement.DecompressionEnabled = true; // this appear to done nothing
                httpBindingElement.AllowCookies = true;
                httpBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                httpBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.Elements.Add(httpBindingElement);
                client = new WebServiceSoapClient(result, ep);
                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Global.App.Credentials.UserName.ToString();
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Global.App.Credentials.Password ?? "";

                string text = client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password;
                byte[] encodedByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
                string base64Encoded = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(encodedByte);

        
                var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Authorization", base64Encoded},
                    {"Culture", CultureName},
                    {"Accept-encoding", "identity"}
                };
                var behavior = new AddHttpHeaderMessageEndpointBehavior(headers);

                client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behavior);

Also I take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-compression-encoder
but System.ServiceModel.Description is not available for maui so things such IPolicyExportExtension cannot be used (correct me if i'm wrong).
How can I decompress the response then?
P.S. I have no access to the server side
